# Cell value based on either of 4 other cells

Tags: excel-formula

What is the simplest formula in Excel to get my result column to show 1 if col1 is not empty, 2 if col2 is not empty, etc.? There will always only be one value in a row.

[image]

Comment: What kind of values are entered in that table? Numbers? Strings?

Comment: the values are strings

Comment: Assuming that the first row is B3:E3: `=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK(B3:E3))*{1,2,3,4})`

Comment: In case you actually have much more columns than just 4, you should replace the manual array `{1,2,3,4}` with something like `COLUMNS` or `SEQUENCE`

Comment: this gives me the result 10 in all situations.....

Comment: That's odd, it works for me and the logic seems correct. When there is a value in column 2, the `NOT(ISBLANK(...))` returns {0,1,0,0} which is then multiplied by {1,2,3,4} so the resulting array is {0,2,0,0}, the sum of which is 2

Comment: Are you sure that the other colums are really empty? Or do they just not have a value? E.g. when you write `=""` into a cell, it will have no value but it is not empty

Comment: In that case, try `=SUM((LEN(B3:E3)>0)*{1,2,3,4})` instead. Instead of checking if a cell is truly empty, this only checks if it has a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited as I misunderstood the question:
This should solve your issue.

```
=MATCH(TRUE;NOT(ISBLANK(B2:E2));0)
```

See the result

[image: This is my result]

Comment: Given OP's answer in comments, it seems the cells are not truly empty. Would require `(LEN(B2:E2)>0)` instead of `NOT(ISBLANK(B2:E2))` then

Comment: Can you help me adjusting the formula, so that it differs between a string and a formula in a cell? A formula in a cell should then count as a blank.

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen the comment of Dattel Klauber provides the soltution, just change NOT(ISBLANK(xxx)) to (LEN(xxx)>0)

Comment: Does not work - I would like to use the ISFORMULA instead. Is that possible?

Comment: isformula would return true for all cells when all cells contain a formula, LEN would return the length of the return value, what kind of error do you get? something that is replicable?